# .htaccess blocking even php access

Tags: php, linux, windows, .htaccess

I want to deny access to a txt file that contains database details, but with the current method I find even the scripts cannot access the details they need. I will be moving this setup from windows to linux and back periodically so need a solution that is not brittle.

```
# Refuse direct access to all files
Order allow,deny
Allow from 127.0.0.1
Deny from all
```

Comment: I would suggest storing the database details using a more secure method such as inside your code. These sorts of details don't change much..

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. But in this application this is the desired approach. Trying to make the best out of a bad bunch

Comment: How about storing the txt file in a directory that is not web accessible?

Comment: Again due to the nature of this application being redeployed constantly over windows and linux the desired approach is within a web accessible folder. Not ideal I know

Answer (score 0):

Not the strongest secured method but you can use a rule like this in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?yourdomain\.com/ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^secret\.txt$ - [F,NC]
```

Replace `secret.txt` with your txt filename and `yourdomain.com` with your actual domain name

This will block web access to `secret.txt` from everywhere except when REFERRER is from your own site.